# MongoDB & Prisma: unilateral M-to-N relation

Tags: javascript, typescript, mongodb, graphql, prisma

Is there a way to make an unilateral m-to-n relation or must both collections have each other's ids? I'm trying to do something like this:

```
model Country {
  id              String    @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  name            String    @unique
  users           User[]
}

model User {
  id              String    @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  userName        String    @unique
  countryIds      String[]  @db.ObjectId
  countries       Country[] @relation(fields: [countryIds], references: [id])
  // ....
}
```

But prisma is making me add another field to `Country` to store the users ids... Like this:

```
model Country {
  id              String    @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  name            String    @unique
  userIds         String[]  @db.ObjectId
  users           Player[]  @relation(fields: [userIds], references: [id])
}
```

I don't need that data and it's not logically needed. Is there any way to bypass that? Any workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some testing I've found that if I leave that userIds field, even though it does not exist in any document, the user's countries could still be correctly queried. The only drawback(not really) is that I can't query the users from the countries. But I guess it makes sense since if I actually needed to query them, adding the userIds relation to the country would also make sense. The actual problem is the error that doesn't let me build/run the code without userIds even though it works fine without it.

**EDIT:**

My schema ended up like this *@Min Somai*:

```
model Country {
  id              String    @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  name            String    @unique
  userIds         String[]  @db.ObjectId
  users           User[]    @relation(fields: [countryIds], references: [id])
}

model User {
  id              String    @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  userName        String    @unique
  countryIds      String[]  @db.ObjectId
  countries       Country[] @relation(fields: [countryIds], references: [id])
  // ....
}
```

Comment: can you share your sample code? It's giving me empty arrays. Seems like prisma doesn't support one way relation. https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/12725